# Add multiple images in UITextView long text

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitextview

I would like to know how to build a `UITextView` with images inserted in the text. I know I can [add them as attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28424571/2064585) but I would like to introduce a challenge on top of that: I would like to **add padding at the text but not at the images**, like shown in the picture. (Do not look at the initial image of the capital letter)

How can I do?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using a `UIWebView` in place of the `UITextView`. I render a local HTML page which is easier to customize in these cases.
Once you create your own HTML page in your favourite editor, you drag it into your Xcode project. Then you just have to tell your `UIWebView` the path to the page to be rendered:

```
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "<name of html file>", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "<name of the directory>")!)
    self.webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
```

In my case, I put the html page and the images I render in a separate folder imported in the project; then you have to reference that folder when generating the URL.

For a better result I've set `scalePageToFit = true` and disabled all the other options of the `UIWebView`. Moreover, in order to disable the zooming by the user, I implemented the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?` to simply returning `nil` value to a better user experience.

Remember to set `self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self`

Comment: Hey Nicholas. Facing same issue. It would have been great to have a more detailed answer with an example ;)