# Adding image inside textview using native NStextattachment and NSattributedString in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I just tried to add an image inside the textview using native NSAtrributedstring and NStextAttachment, getting some help from this article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010035/how-to-add-image-and-text-in-uitextview-in-ios)

However, I am unable to do it. I am using nativescript-mediafilepicker library to add the image from the Photo library, then converting the PH image to UIImage using one its inbuilt method. But the textview is not getting updated with the image. However, I am being able to add more string through the NSattributedstring but not image.

here's my code.

```
                  //creating and initilizing new NSMutableAttributedString
                   var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString.alloc().initWithString(textview.ios.text);
                   textview.ios.attributedText = attributedString;

                  //value is an UIImage object what the convertPHImageToUIImage method returns
                   var image = value;

                  console.log(image);
                  //the above log prints<UIImage: 0x2817ac4d0> size {4032, 3024} orientation 0 scale 1.000000



                  let oldWidth = image.size.width;
                  // console.log(oldWidth);
                  let scaleFactor = oldWidth / (textview.ios.frame.size.width - 10);
                    //console.log(scaleFactor);
                  let orientation="up";

                    //create NStextAttachment

                   let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment.alloc().init();
                   //adding UIImage object to NSTextAttachment
                    textAttachment.image = UIImage.imageWithCGImageScaleOrientation(image.CGImage ,scaleFactor , orientation)
                  // console.dir(textAttachment);

                   //creating a new NSAttributedString
                    let attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString.alloc().init();
                    //console.dir(attrStringWithImage);
                    attrStringWithImage.attachment = textAttachment;
                    console.dir(attrStringWithImage)

                   //appenind the NSAttributedString to the mutable string..
                    attributedString.appendAttributedString(attrStringWithImage);
                    //console.log(attributedString.containsAttachmentsInRange(textview.ios.selectedRange));
                    textview.ios.attributedText = attributedString;

                     //textview.ios.textStorage.insertAttributedStringAtIndex(attrStringWithImage,textview.ios.selectedRange.location)
                    //this doesn't work either
```

Comment: Please note! I am an amateur to development. Please forgive if I am asking something silly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Install [tns-platform-declarations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) if you are using TypeScript, that will make your life easy when you want to access native apis.

```
UIImage.imageWithCGImageScaleOrientation(cgImage, scale, orientation);
```

This [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) will help you understanding the casting of Objective C to JavaScript / TypeScript.

Comment: HelloSir, thanks a lot. Understood the concept of using parameter name's first letter as capital with "With". thanks a lot. I will implement this now. Hope it works

Comment: Hello Sir, after implementing the same I am getting this weird log wheneven the medifilepicker opens :  "Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread. Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.
Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.
Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.
Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.
Connecting to XPCPhotoLibraryStore"

Comment: What is your source for your image? Can you reproduce the issue with Playground?

Comment: Hello Sir,  I could come till this far but still, the textview is not getting updated with the Image. I was also taking reference from this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28424045/combining-text-and-images-in-uitextview#28424571   I have put my code in the question now.

Comment: `app/images/1.jpg` will not be a known path to UIImage.

Comment: hello sir, now I have converted the PhImage into UIImage using the Mediafile picker plugin's convertPHImageToUIImage() method. And when I log the image in the console it display "<UIImage: 0x2817ac4d0> size {4032, 3024} orientation 0 scale 1.000000". But still not textview is not getting updated with the image. I have updated the question.

Comment: What you have in your XML, are you using data binding on value attribute of your text view?

Comment: Yes! Sir! I am using two way data binding on the xml

Comment: However attributedStringwithImage is still showing length as zero after adding the NStextattachment

Comment: It's valid, you can't expect both to work. The text will overwrite the attributed string or vice versa based on which gets applied last. You will have to use formatted text and inject your image by modifying the native instance of attributed string. I guess you might have to extend the TextView component to get it right.

Comment: Thank you Sir. But can you tell me a bit more abourt "extending the textview component". Sorry to bother you again.

Comment: Here you can find some example - https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/ui-plugin-custom, but it doesn't necessarily have to be a plugin. It can be a module with in the app as along you prefer that way. You might have to understand the hierarchy of the TextView component, https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/text-view/text-view.ios.ts and update the formatted text utility class to support image.

Comment: HelloSir, I am looking into those articles. However, there was an error in my code as well. The attributedStringwithImage was not getting initialized correctly with the textattachment . then I used "initWithStringAttributes()" method to initialize as initWithAttachment() didn't work. However the image still not showing up on the UI.  I have also opened another straightforward question to see if I can get anyhelp.